# Best way for storing data-string relative to elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What is the best, most possible, `proper` way to store data inside elements?

I used to use a separated `XML` file and now i'm using the `Tag` and `tooltip` property.

It's a string-type data, e.g.:

Theme data `Theme1.fg.ffffffff;Theme2.fg.ff000000;`

Margins according to window size `Margin.16:9.10,5,10,5;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With WPF/XAML an ideal approach could be to store such strings in `Resources` of the respective element or in a `ResourceDictionary`

eg

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="ThemeData">Theme1.fg.ffffffff;Theme2.fg.ff000000;</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="Margins">Margin.16:9.10,5,10,5;</sys:String>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

to use the same you have two approach

xaml approach

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ThemeData}" />
```

code behind

```
string themeData = myGrid.FindResource("ThemeData");
```

these resources can also be stored in a `ResourceDictionary` which can further be merged in any element, window or even whole application

eg

StringResources.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <sys:String x:Key="ThemeData">Theme1.fg.ffffffff;Theme2.fg.ff000000;</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="Margins">Margin.16:9.10,5,10,5;</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

usage

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="StringResources.xaml" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ThemeData}" />
</Grid>
```

or this if you want to merge/override some more resources

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="StringResources.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--define new resource or even override existing for this specific element -->
            <sys:String x:Key="ThemeData">Theme1.fg.ff00ff00;Theme2.fg.ff0000ff;</sys:String>
            <sys:String x:Key="NewMargins">Margin.16:9.10,5,10,5;</sys:String>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ThemeData}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: That's exactly what i did if you've read the comments on the previous answer with a little bit of modifying :D .. but here you go (Y) for understanding me ;) and thank you btw

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood, you can use Tag property on controls to store the info . it accepts object type. hence you can attach any type to it. like control.Tag = objectyouwantto attach.
if my answer seems not relevant, please elaborate your question

Comment: That's right i can, but what's so different with the tag property? it's exactly the same as the tooltip! .. i was hoping for a proper way more like something different.

Comment: @Hossam, tool tip is just for text that appears when you hover over the item.  Tag property was added specifically there for stuffing anything you want into the object.

Comment: @paqogomez thanks for replying, and since we're already getting out of the point, i'm already using the tag as an integer value for firing triggers .. the point of the question as i said above that i want a different way because as you said a tooltip is used as a text on hover

Comment: If you need more properties, just make your own object.  Have it inherit from your original object and add some properties to it.

Comment: you can do what  @paqogomez has suggested by inheriting original object. OR you can create a custom class that has one property of int for your triggers and other property of type you want to store the data string and attach this object as tag

Comment: Thank you, that got me the perfect idea .. i can use a .resx file and even can compile it into a binary and include it in the assembly (Y)